# Akka.NET - how to suppress the logging of an intentional child actor failure?

Tags: akka.net

I have a parent/child actor relationship where--just like what was encouraged in the Akka.NET Bootcamp--the so-called "risky" behaviour is pushed to a child actor. In my case, network-related exceptions are expected and when they happen, the child will simply get destroyed, reincarnated, and ready to try again. It's quite convenient actually.

My only problem is that my console/log is getting flooded with exception stack traces from these natural actor failure/restarts. I want to turn off fault logging for that one actor. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Good question - off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to do a log filter for a specific actor. Let me check with our team and see.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I found a workaround: I disabled `Akka.Event.DefaultLogger` via hocon config and used an EventBus monitoring actor to do the required filtering and then delegate all other log items to the regular ASP.NET logging system.

Comment: In [Phobos](https://phobos.petabridge.com/) we have a pretty detailed system for filtering traces from specific actors or by specific message types - I wonder if we could do something like that for the `ILoggingAdapter` in the future...